# Pregenerating ConTeXt MarkIV format. This may take some time... takes forever

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, latex

Hey there I tried to install latex using the follwing commands in ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full texstudio
```

Then I finally came to the point with the following output:

```
Setting up thunderbird-locale-en (1:52.3.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ... 
Setting up thunderbird-locale-en-us (1:52.3.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ... 
Setting up context (2015.05.18.20150601-2) ... 
Running mtxrun --generate. This may take some time... done. 
Pregenerating ConTeXt MarkIV format. This may take some time...
```

And after waiting for 5 hours I closed the process. Unfortunately now my certain packages seem to be broken. e.g when I try to install a new package or try sudo apt-get dist-upgrade I get the following error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure
-a' to correct the problem.
```

And If I try

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I came again to the endless waiting point....

Any Ideas what I can do?

Notes:

- I also have installed Miktex before does that cause some troubles?
- I unfortunately cannot remove any package cause I also get:

  ```
   sudo apt-get remove tex-common
   E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
  ```

Comment: Same here, installing TexLive-full broke my dpkg on Linux Mint. I had MikTex installed too, because all I wanted was access to the csquotes package. Now I can't work at all since dpkg doesn't do anything any more. Rebooting does nothing, I don't even want to figure out how to reinstall a deeply embedded package like dpkg.

Answer (score 20):

The issue is still here. Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> in console doe the job.

The point is that the script `luatex --ini --lua=/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-cod.lua ...` tries to read something from 0th fd which is opened for `/dev/pts/1`. Maybe it tries to ask some question and waits for an answer in interactive manner. I just pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it sufficed.

Comment: This needs to be reported as a bug. There are proper mechanisms for asking for input during package installation.

Comment: I had to hit enter multiple times !

Comment: Damn, this nearly broke my upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04. Thank you all

Answer (score 5):

I have also faced the similar issue.
What have I done is :

1. Run **sudo dpkg --configure -a**
2. Got the following response and it stuck for a long time.

   > Setting up context (2018.04.04.20180416-1~18.04.york1)...
   >   Running mtxrun --generate. This may take some time...`
3. I entered ctr-c
4. Got the following response.

   > Errors were encountered while processing:
   >   context
   >   context-modules
   >   texlive-full
5. removed these packages using dpkg -r.

   > sudo dpkg -r context-modules.
   >   sudo dpkg -r context.
   >   sudo dpkg -r texlive-full.
6. Now again I run dpkg --configure -a
7. This time it does not get stuck .

Comment: This worked for me (Ubuntu 20), but I had to restart and run sudo dpkg -r context separately.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever at any step, just press `Enter` and keep holding it until it gets unstuck. It did work out for me.
Try this method first before moving to any harsh steps like other answers are mentioning.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I am new to linux (only few days and I crashed it 4 times already :D)... I faced the same problem while installing `texlive-full` - `apt-get install`, `purge` and so on didn't worked and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` couldn't finish. I don't know which step helped the most, but after searching on the internet I found the solution how to 'repair' damages.

1. open second terminal and type `sudo killall dpkg`
2. I opened `sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status` and deleted the whole section for `Package: context (2015.05.18.20150601-2)` (you can easily search it by pressing `ctrl+W`) and saved it. That didn't solved problem yet (I also removed 'tex-common' since that was problematic for me, too).
3. I tried to remove problematic package with dpkg: `sudo dpkg -r context` but dependency error occurred (`texlive-full` and `context-modules` depends on `context`) and processing triggered for 'tex-common'. So I try to remove `tex-common` but there were even more dependencies I didn't try to remove other packages.
4. I tried to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and an error occured -> thats good because it stopped working and I could try `apt-get`.
5. I typed `sudo apt-get purge texlive*` to remove everything from problematic package and it worked, than I also purged `miktex`.
6. The last step was about repairing apt-get: `sudo apt-get -f install`

I think I was just lucky but after this you can try installing tex again (find some not bugged package)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue with my `texlive-*full` and terminal got stuck for more than 12hrs. Finally I have decided to quit the upgrade. I have used following steps to resolve my problem through trial and error and a comprehensive search over Google.

1. Open the dpkg status file situated at `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and delete all the block information which contains the status  `unpacked` or `not-installed` or `half-installed`(Only choose those packages which are installed during Texlive, don't forget to remove context).
2. Remove the dpkg lock using `sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock` to kill the process.
3. Use `sudo dpkg -r  <packagename>` to remove installed package..
4. Use `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to configure all packages.
5. Most probably, now you can able to update or upgrade the apt.
6. Remove all the files related to texlive by using  `sudo apt purge texlive-*`.
7. Use `sudo apt autoremove` to uninstall unwanted or leftover files.

I have also reinstalled the `tex-common` and `texlive-base` and now my system is working fine.  You might need to use steps 1 to 4 recursively until your problem has been resolved. I have also restarted my PC after step 4.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04. None of the previous answers seemed to help: `sudo dpkg -r` did not work, nor did pressing Enter, and the `tex-common` and `texlive-base` did not contain all the packages I required.

What did help was to use

```
sudo apt-mark hold context
sudo apt-mark hold context-modules
```

Then run

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: To get it unstuck, you have to press <Enter> many times, not just once and then wait for a few minutes. There is no need for any `dpkg -r`