Upgrade of Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 is blocked at pregenerating of the context
The upgrade of my laptop is blocked and no progress since at least 30 minutes.
I am wondering if it could take more than 1 hour? What I can do if no progress after more to 2 hours?

Thanks in advance

Answer found here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/956006/pregenerating-context-markiv-format-this-may-take-some-time-takes-forever

How I can close this question as it is a duplicate? Thanks

That terminal (shown during upgrade) does not usually allow any user input. Did hitting enter work there?

This is a good question. Why was it downvoted?
