Ubuntu update stuck on Fontconfig error
This is ridiculous, but my whole distro update from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 is stuck on simple Fontconfig error: Cannot load config file from /etc/fonts/fonts.conf.
The update is stuck almost at its end on "Installing the upgrades" step since yesterday without progress.
Is there any way to save the upgrade instead of canceling all and restarting just because of some font error?
I see many ways showing how solve this Fontconfig error in normal situations, but not during update. I cannot even open terminal, clicking on it does nothing. And restart would probably mess up the state in unpredictable way since I am in the middle of an update.
UPD: clarified that "from Ubuntu 18.04" means upgrading to newer Ubuntu, ie 20.04.
I also now tried to reboot in recovery mode and run dpkg to fix packages but arrived at absolutely same step which cause problem: "Updating ConText MarkIV format. This may take some time..." hanging around 30 minutes already.

Amazing, so if I want to get to supported version, I actually can't and all questions are ignored? If that is the case, probably time to move away from Ubuntu all together.

I am upgrading distro to supported 20.04. At the end of this upgrade I encountered the mentioned error. Sorry if that was not clear.

Have you explored system logs for clues; ie. does anything show when you view dmesg or journalctl etc....  You've checked you have valid files there (not disk issues etc) and that your system isn't stuck because of hardware problems etc..  Is this a desktop or server system? (we're limited to details you provide)

This maybe helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/956006/pregenerating-context-markiv-format-this-may-take-some-time-takes-forever  (ie. have you checked it's not waiting for you to answer an easily overlooked prompt..)

@guiverc not sure whether to laugh or cry, but that indeed helped, thanks! I tried before to click random buttons in terminal, but apparently one really need to hold Enter until it comes back to life. Finally on Ubuntu 20.04!

feel free to write up your own answer... This question maybe marked duplicate of the link I provided ^, but you maybe able to accept your answer and thus gain some rep before then.  Well done for getting there; and yeah, "laugh/cry" is a common response when dealing with complex systems like computers...
